# AngularJS - ReferenceError: success is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting "ReferenceError: success is not defined" when doing a Restful call from controller to my node.js back end as follows:

authControllers.js:

```
authControllers.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService',
function authCtrl($scope, $location, $window, UserService, AuthenticationService) {
  $scope.me = function() {    
    UserService.me(function(res) {
      $scope.myDetails = res;
    }, function() {
      console.log('Failed to fetch details');
      $rootScope.error = 'Failed to fetch details';
    })
  };      
}]);
```

authServices.js:

```
authServices.factory('UserService',['$http', function($http) {
  return {        
    me:function() {
    return $http.get(options.api.base_url + '/me').success(success).error(error)
    }
  }
}]);
```

html:

```
<div class="row" data-ng-controller="authCtrl" data-ng-init="me()">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <strong>Your Details</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>{{myDetails.data.username}}</p>
                <p>{{myDetails.data.email}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A successful nodeJs call is being received and it's returning data as well, but 
couldn't get it in the front end. Please help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is:

```
return $http.get(options.api.base_url + '/me').success(success).error(error)
```

To fix it, don't try to reference `success` and `error` functions that don't exist.

```
return $http.get(options.api.base_url + '/me')
```

Angular returns a `$q` promise when you call `$http`, which you use correctly. The success and error resolution methods are deprecated.

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated.

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 2):

.success and .error are not part of the $http.get call. $http.get itself is a promise so when calling your service you need to have

```
authControllers.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$window', 'UserService', 'AuthenticationService',
function authCtrl($scope, $location, $window, UserService, AuthenticationService) {
  $scope.me = function() {    
    UserService.me().then(function(res) {
      $scope.myDetails = res;
    }, function() {
      console.log('Failed to fetch details');
      $rootScope.error = 'Failed to fetch details';
    })
  };      
}]);
```

and your service is to be kept simple:

```
authServices.factory('UserService',['$http', function($http) {
  return {        
    me:function() {
    return $http.get(options.api.base_url + '/me');
    }
  }
}]);
```

More on [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)